# Spring endpoints without dependency Spring-Boot-Data-REST-Starter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

I Have a Repository and Controller,

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/people")
    public Iterable<Person> getPeople() {
        return repository.findAll();

    }
    @PostMapping("/people")
    public void addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        repository.save(person);
    }
}
```

and I want to create **endpoint** /people but this doesn't work without the dependency Spring-Boot-Data-REST-Starter.
The question is : is it possible to create an endpoint without the Spring-Boot-Data-REST-Starter dependency?

here's my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have a message : Started Application, but the process is finished with exit code 0, so nothing is up.

Comment: I had similar issue where if I give `@RequestMapping` to the `class` itself it worked, if I don't it didn't work. You could try adding `@RequestMapping` to the `@RestController`. And I don't use that dependancy.

Comment: @Praveen M, do you mean, "@RequestMapping("/")
@RestController", can you post your controller and pom? thanks.

Comment: Other way around on two lines and try with a word `/api` before you go with just `/`

Comment: @Praveen M, i did RequestMapping("/controller") above RestController annotation but it's not working. the process is finished with exit code 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```